# Reference Cursor If Then Use Cursor in Loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I was trying to use something like this:

```
 DECLARE type cur1 REF CURSOR;
 c1 cur1;

  BEGIN 
   IF (variable1 = 'true') THEN 
     OPEN c1 FOR 'SELECT * FROM STUDENT'; 
   ELSE 
     OPEN c1 FOR 'SELECT * FORM EMP';
 END IF ; 
  END;
```

That I got from [PL/SQL cursor with IF condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144230/pl-sql-cursor-with-if-condition)

However, I then need to loop through the cursor to use the data. So I am trying to figure out how to do the following.

```
DECLARE type cur1 REF CURSOR;
 c1 cur1;

  BEGIN 
   IF (variable1 = 'true') THEN 
     OPEN c1 FOR 'SELECT * FROM STUDENT'; 
   ELSE 
     OPEN c1 FOR 'SELECT * FORM EMP';
 END IF ;
    for award_rec in c1 loop ....
  END;
```

But I get the following error

> PLS-00221: 'c1' is not a procedure or is undefined

How should I structure this?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but: the comparison operator is `=`, so it should be `if variable = 'true'`. The `:=` is for an _assignment_ not for a comparison

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name you are correct about the = and I forgot to change that in the question.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use for loop with a `REF CURSOR`. Instead fetch it in a loop with `EXIT WHEN` condition.  As the table (and hence the columns) to be selected are different for each condition, you must include loops in both conditions.

You can use a `BULK COLLECT INTO`  clause to fetch the records into a collection of corresponding table records.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
TYPE cur1
IS
  REF
  CURSOR;
    c1 cur1;
    variable1 VARCHAR2(10) := 'true';
  TYPE emprec_t
IS
  TABLE OF emp%ROWTYPE;
TYPE student_t
IS
  TABLE OF student%ROWTYPE;
  emp_rec emprec_t;
  stu_rec student_t;
BEGIN
  IF (variable1 = 'true') THEN
    OPEN c1 FOR 'SELECT * FROM STUDENT';
    FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO stu_rec;
  FOR i IN stu_rec.FIRST..stu_rec.LAST
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stu_rec(i).STUDENT_ID);
  END LOOP;
ELSE
  OPEN c1 FOR 'SELECT * FROM  EMP';
  FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO emp_rec;
  FOR i IN emp_rec.FIRST..emp_rec.LAST
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emp_rec(i).EMPLOYEE_ID);
  END LOOP;
END IF ;
END;
/
```

**EDIT**: You can loop through the collection and fetch columns from a particular index as shown.

Comment: Thanks Kaushik Nayak!  However, I am getting an error when I am trying to loop through emp_rec like... for award_rec in emp_rec loop
      EXIT when ng_rec%NOTFOUND;  I get that emp_rec is not a cursor.

Comment: Made a mistake. I am getting an error when I am trying to access the cursor emp_rec.field it is giving me the error I must declare them.

Comment: I have modified the code. Check now. You need to access the emp_rec collection using a loop and fetch individual columns.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to take care of my issue another way so I don't need the if in the cursor.

Comment: Ok!!. At least you can upvote the answer since it answers the question :)-